# File not created in Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, file

So I've been doing like the simplest thing ever. Create a text file for a Java application. Just directly in the C directory:

```
File file = new File("C://function.txt");
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

The file never shows up though, I changed the slashes, changed the path, nothing. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: 6 answers in less than 10 minutes, oh man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just creating a `File` object, not a file itself. So in-order to create new file you need use below command:

`file .createNewFile();`

This would create your file under `C:\` drive. Maybe you can also check if it is already exsits and handle exception etc.

Comment: This way I get an exception: 

java.io.IOException: Access denied
 at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
 at michal.functiondrawer.Chart.createDataset(Chart.java:48)
 at michal.functiondrawer.Chart.<init>(Chart.java:25)
 at michal.functiondrawer.Main.main(Main.java:5)

Comment: Then you don't have access to create directory under "C:\" drive. You need to change the path or provide access.

Answer (score 3):

There are many methods to create a new file with java : **(You should firstly  verify the permission to create a file in that folder c:** )

1. ```
    String path = "C:"+File.separator"function.txt";
    File f = new File(path);
    f.mkdirs(); 
    f.createNewFile();
   ```

   __ or

   ```
    try {
   //What ever the file path is.
   File f = new File("C:/function.txt");
   FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(f);
   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
   Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
   w.write("Line 1!!");
   w.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("Problem writing to the file function.txt");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

After Java 7, you should use the [new I/O API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) instead of the File class to create new files.

Here is an example:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C://function.txt");
try {
    Files.createFile(path);
    System.out.println(Files.exists(path));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Okay, but again...
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\function.txt
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Unknown Source)
 at michal.functiondrawer.Chart.createDataset(Chart.java:49)
 at michal.functiondrawer.Chart.<init>(Chart.java:26)
 at michal.functio...

Comment: The problem is, that in Windows 7/8, you do by default not have write access to the root folder of your C drive. see here: http://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/cant-create-file-in-the-c-drive-root-directory-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not exist you can create a new file like:

```
if(!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("Created a new File");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this:

```
 String path = "C:"+File.separator+"function.txt";

 File file = new File(path);
 System.out.println(file.exists());
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
File file = new File("C://function.txt");
if (!file.isFile())
    file.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
File file = new File("C:/test.text");
f.createNewFile();
```